# How to reference variables from listboxes in the main code of a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Say I had a userform with 3 options:

```
Listbox1: Item 1 
          Item 2 
          Item 3
```

I want to reference them in the main code, like:

```
If Listbox1 = *Item 1*
     do something
```

or

```
*Item 1* = 400
```

How do I reference *Item 1* in the code? Would it be Listbox1.1? Listbox1 = 1? "Item 1"?

Comment: If VBE, if you view the form as an object (View:Object or Shft-F7) and select the list (or any item on the form) then the properties window will tell you what the name is.

Comment: Is it a `ListBox`, or a `ComboBox`? If it's a combobox, you can use the `.Text` property to get the selected item. If it's an actual listbox, depends whether you're allowing multiple selections or not. To work out the selected item(s) you need to traverse the list and check if `listbox1.Selected(i)` for each item. List items aren't supposed to be editable - what's "Item 1 = 400" supposed to be?

Comment: Say the selectable item from the listbox is Hydrogen. I would want to update a variable value to the density of hydrogen after the listbox is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple example illustrating the concept. As Mathieu Guindon pointed out in a comment, you can use `ListBox.Text`.

Suppose you have the following user form which is opened by clicking the button "Show User Form". I assume from your question that you would like to do something like selecting an item in the list and then do something in the code when you click the OK button. In my example, clicking OK launches the Message Box showing which item was selected, but you could of course do whatever you want. The code that generates the messsage box is located in a regular module, while the code for the OK button and Listbox is located in the user form.

[image]

The button "Show User Form" simply calls the following sub in the regular module:

```
Public Sub ShowForm1()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This displays the user form, which is initialized with the following code:

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .AddItem "Item 1"
        .AddItem "Item 2"
    End With
End Sub
```

The code below for the OK button includes the reference `Me.ListBox1.Text` that captures the selected item and stores it in a variable which is then passed to the subroutine `ShowMsgBox` in the regular module. Note the use of `Me.` which is shorthand for referencing the user form where the listbox is located (i.e. the same form as the OK button):

```
Private Sub okButton_Click()
    sSelectedItem = Me.ListBox1.Text
    ShowMsgBox (sSelectedItem)
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The code above calls `ShowMsgBox`, which is in the regular module:

```
Public Sub ShowMsgBox(sInput As String)
    MsgBox "You selected " & sInput & ".", vbOKOnly
    ' Other code to do something with the selected item goes here.
End Sub
```

Note that in `ShowMsgBox()` you no longer reference the listbox, but rather work with the value `sInput` passed as an argument.

Hope you find this useful.

**EDIT:**

Following Skye's comment, here is a suggestion on how to open other forms instead of a message box. You must replace one line in `okButton_Click()`
, like this:

```
Private Sub okButton_Click()
    sSelectedItem = Me.ListBox1.Text
    ShowOtherUserForm (sSelectedItem)
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Then, in the regular module, add the sub `ShowOtherUserForm()`. This sub uses `Select Case` to check which item was selected. You can do the same job with `If`, but I prefer the `Select` style for this scenario. My example requires that you have two userforms called "OtherForm1" and "OtherForm2".

```
Sub ShowOtherUserForm(sInput As String)
    Dim x As Object ' Must be "Object", declare "As UserForm" won't work.
    Select Case sInput
        Case "Item 1"
            Set x = OtherForm1
        Case "Item 2"
            Set x = OtherForm2
    End Select
    x.Show
End Sub
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Comment: This is very similar, but what I would like to open instead of a message box, is a different userform based on the selection in the list box. I've been trying to work with If statements, but I haven't been successful with getting it to work.

Comment: @Skye, check out my edit for a suggestion on how to open another user form instead of a message box. This uses `Select` instead of `If`, but it's more or less the same logic. Maybe worth exploring some tutorial, like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_userforms.htm).

Comment: I got it to work the way I wanted it. Thanks for your help!